# Flutter hive clearing box during swiping between tabs

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-hive

In my case we have 3 tabs in `TabController` and in all of this pages we have some data which we want to use them, now on each tab when we are swiping between them we don't have previous data and length of `box` values is `0`, you suppose we have three tab as:

```
screen_a
screen_b
screen_c
```

into `screen_a` we have:

```dart
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() =>MyHome();
}

class MyHome extends State<Home> {
  late Box<Level> _level;
  late List<Level> levels ;
  late VideoPlayerController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _level = Hive.box<Level>('level');
    levels = _level.values.toList();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
```

now on starting application we have many data on `screen_a` and after swiping on `screen_b` and going back to `screen_a` we don't have any data in `hive` :| :|

what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should store your tabs' data in a bloc or controller class that does not lose state and data when switching between tabs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately it does not work

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your overall use case and how you want your `TabViews` to behave, but you can work with the `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` to ensure that your state of the `StatefulWidget` stays intact when switching tabs. This also ensures that the content of your `StatefulWidget` does not have to be rebuild when switching tabs, but will still use resources (just to keep in mind for performance considerations when working with more complex scenarios):

```dart
class MyHome extends State<Home> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  /// Here you can either add custom logic to determine when
  /// this tab should be kept "alive" - for now returning [true]
  /// will work out.
  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

  ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately it does not work